# failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I gonna to install these pallets in `node/Cargo.toml` :

```
# pallet-authority-discovery = '3.0.0'
# pallet-im-online = '3.0.0'
# sc-authority-discovery = '0.9.0'
# sc-consensus-epochs = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-chain-spec = { version = '3.0.0' }
# sc-consensus-slots = '0.9.0'
# sc-consensus-babe = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-consensus-babe-rpc = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-finality-grandpa-rpc = '0.9.0'
# sc-network = '0.9.0'
# sc-sync-state-rpc = '0.9.0'
# sp-authority-discovery = '3.0.0'
# sp-consensus-babe = { version = '0.9.0' }
```

but i faced this error :

> error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
> ... required by package `sp-core v3.0.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `sp-core = "^3.0.0"` of package `sp-api v3.0.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `sp-api = "^3.0.0"` of package `sp-consensus v0.9.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `sp-consensus = "^0.9.0"` of package `sp-consensus-babe v0.9.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `sp-consensus-babe = "^0.9.0"` of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/kianoush/projects/substrate-node-template/node)`
> versions that meet the requirements `^0.9.0` are: 0.9.0

> the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
> package `parity-util-mem v0.12.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.12"` of package `kvdb v0.12.0`
> ... which satisfies dependency `kvdb = "^0.12.0"` of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32#5ea6d953)`
> ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/kianoush/projects/substrate-node-template/node)`
> Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.
> failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` which could resolve this conflict

what the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

```
[package]
name = "node-template"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate node, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"
build = "build.rs"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[[bin]]
name = "node-template"

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.0.9", features = ["derive"] }
futures = { version = '0.3.9', features = ['compat'] }
hex-literal = '0.3.1'
# pallet-authority-discovery = '3.0.0'
# pallet-im-online = '3.0.0'
# sc-authority-discovery = '0.9.0'
# sc-consensus-epochs = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-chain-spec = { version = '3.0.0' }
# sc-consensus-slots = '0.9.0'
# sc-consensus-babe = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-consensus-babe-rpc = { version = '0.9.0' }
# sc-finality-grandpa-rpc = '0.9.0'
# sc-network = '0.9.0'
# sc-sync-state-rpc = '0.9.0'
# sp-authority-discovery = '3.0.0'
# sp-consensus-babe = { version = '0.9.0' }
sp-keystore = '0.13.0'

sc-cli = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", features = ["wasmtime"] , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-executor = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", features = ["wasmtime"] , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-service = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", features = ["wasmtime"] , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-telemetry = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-keystore = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-transaction-pool-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-consensus = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-consensus = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-finality-grandpa = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-finality-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-client-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-runtime = { version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-keyring = { version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }

# These dependencies are used for the node template's RPCs
jsonrpsee = { version = "0.15.1", features = ["server"] }
sc-rpc = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-rpc-api = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-blockchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sp-block-builder = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
sc-basic-authorship = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
substrate-frame-rpc-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }

# These dependencies are used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
frame-benchmarking-cli = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }

# Local Dependencies
node-template-runtime = { version = "4.0.0-dev", path = "../runtime" }

# CLI-specific dependencies
try-runtime-cli = { version = "0.10.0-dev", optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-build-script-utils = { version = "3.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.32" }
vergen = '7.4.3'

[features]
default = []
# Dependencies that are only required if runtime benchmarking should be build.
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "node-template-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-benchmarking-cli/runtime-benchmarks",
]
# Enable features that allow the runtime to be tried and debugged. Name might be subject to change
# in the near future.
try-runtime = ["node-template-runtime/try-runtime", "try-runtime-cli"]
```

Comment: Include your dependencies in std feature section

Comment: @MrishoLukamba in this Cargo.toml not ant [std] section

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully fix your problem:

```
cargo update -p kvdb@0.12.0 -p parity-util-mem@0.12.0
```

Comment: it dosent work man